# How can I add text to the output returned from my select in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this query:

```
Select Number from CardChoice
```

it returns

```
Number 

1
2 
3
```

How can I add text to that so it returns

```
Batch

Batch 1
Batch 2
Batch 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `||` operator for concatenate string

```
 Select 'Batch '  || Number as Batch from CardChoice
```